# Second image not saving with serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models that looks like this:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=120)


class ChoiceImage(models.Model):
    choice = models.OneToOneField(Choice, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='some-path/')
```

A serializer for the `ChoiceImage` that looks like this:

```
class ChoiceImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    img = Base64ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = ChoiceImage
        fields = ('img',)
```

And a `ChoiceSerializer` that looks like this:

```
class CreateChoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choiceimage = ChoiceImageSerializer(many=False, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ('choice', 'choiceimage')

    def create(self, validated_data):

        image_uploaded = validated_data.get("choiceimage")

        if not image_uploaded["img"]:
            q = validated_data.get("question")
            if not q.choice_set.exists():
                raise APIException("You must upload either an image or a cover.")
            else:

                img = q.choice_set.all()[0].choiceimage.img
                img2 = slice_image(img)
                validated_data["choiceimage"]["img"] = img2

        image_validated_data = validated_data.pop('choiceimage')
        choice = Choice.objects.create(**validated_data)
        image_serializer = self.fields['choiceimage']
        image_validated_data['choice'] = choice

        image_serializer.create(image_validated_data)
```

Basically, the intention is this: A user creates 2 choices. If the user provides no image to the choices, then return an error. Else if the user provides only one image, split the image in half. Save one half to the first choice and the second half to the second choice. Lastly, if two images are uploaded then ignore the split image logic. My logic works fine with no image and two images.

However, when I submit only one image, the image gets sliced in half and the first choice gets that image saved in the database and file path correctly, but when it tries to save the second choice's image it creates the choice and the `ChoiceImage` entry, but the path to that image is empty and the image is not saved in the file path. I'm not sure why this is happening, because I get no error at all. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my image split function:

```
def slice_image(img):
    reader = misc.imread(img)

    height, width, _ = reader.shape
    with_cutoff = width // 2
    s1 = reader[:, :with_cutoff]
    s2 = reader[:, with_cutoff:]

    misc.imsave(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + "/" + img.name, s1)
    return ContentFile(base64.b64encode(np.ascontiguousarray(s2)))
```

Comment: What does ```image_serializer.is_valid()``` say?

Comment: @AndreyNelubin `AssertionError: Cannot call .is_valid() as no data= keyword argument was passed when instantiating the serializer instance.`